# Difference in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am planning on learning SQL.

I am looking at SQLAlchemy, since I am rather familiar with Python.

I am wanting to know, is SQL the same even if the sql is in MySQL or MSSQL or any other. Or is it like saying OOP or scripting is the same, say Python is similar to Java to C++ since loops and fileIO are rather the same, just different syntax.

I thank you in advance for any help on this.

Comment: SQL varies among databases.  There is a standard, so it is not quite disparate as java/python/C++, but there are definitely differences.  Think of the US and UK -- two nations divided by a common language.

Comment: Good thing about `sqlalchemy` is that it will provide you a common interface to deal with different database engines. However, you should get some level of understanding of `SQL` in order to write efficient backend code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ANSI standards for Structured Query Language (SQL.) There's a couple revisions (e.g. ANSI-92) and a couple of levels of "compliance" with those standards. Almost all database engines are compliant with the core syntax (with the keywords and basic statement syntax).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92

But each database is free to add extensions and to deviate from the standard. And there are are some very significant differences, painful differences in terms of statements being "portable" between databases.

Most databases document their level of compliance with the ANSI standards, and the differences with standard SQL.  For example, MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/compatibility.html

It is entirely possible to write a statement that will "work" in almost every database;  for example:

```
select * from emp order by id
```

But once things start getting more involved than the very simple, when we start doing really useful stuff, that's when the differences in SQL become more apparent.